# Is my HDD on its way out?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

The other day I happened to notice my Event Viewer showing numerous Error 7s. "The disk...has a bad block". They have been showing up rapidly over the past couple days. So I installed HD Tune for extra assessment. I attached the pics below. What do you think? Will running chksdk help at all? I did a back up with Macrium just in case. Age of hard drive and PC is 13 years. My PC oddly isn't running slow or anything.

Health:

[image: Health]

Error Scan:

[image: Error Scan]

On another note...if and when the HDD fails, is the OEM product key automatically deactivated? I plan to reinstall Windows on another hard drive. I had bought an extra HDD and Windows installation disks several years ago as the computer was refurbished and preinstalled with Windows.

Comment: It wouldn’t run slowly unless/until your system attempts to read a file on one of the many damaged sectors

Answer (score 1):

1. Age of hard drive and PC is 13 years
2. On another note...if and when the HDD fails, is the OEM product key automatically deactivated?
3. I had bought an extra HDD and Windows installation disks several years ago as the computer was refurbished and preinstalled with Windows.

On 3:  If you have a Windows DVD with a good Key, it will work

On 2: Hard drive dying does not deactivate the license per se. I am pretty sure not for Windows 7;  certainly not for Windows 10 / 11.

On 1:  At 13 years of age, I recommend replacing the computer as other parts could fail. I suppose if you have already paid for the new HDD and Windows DVD then it will not cost you much to try.

If you are going to try, do so immediately as your drive could completely pack it in any day.

Still, however, probably time for a new computer because a lot has changed in 13 years (CPU speeds, SSDs and much larger capacities and speed, newer operating systems).

Comment: Is it possible for the HDD to "appear" to be going bad if other parts were failing, damaged, or loose?

Comment: Yes. That is possible, although hdd's are by far the most likely component to fail (hence the idea of RAID) - and 13 years is a long life for an HDD so its the most likely actiin. It is vonceivable it is a loose cable  or even a power issue  but its unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is on the way out  and it is a good idea to back it up and replace it sooner rather then later.

Windiws licence is not tied to the hard drive, so you wont loose it if you change it. If the computer us from a big manufacturer (like Dell/HP/Lenovo etc) it will be stored in firmware and a new install should find it   If its a white lable / custom box from an independant company that builds PC's you will want to find the Windows key lable or grab it from the system before rebuilding.  (There must be many ways to do this - I used Magic Jelly Bean Key Finder).

Comment: What would happen if I used it until it died, and then replaced it? I notice many advise to replace it asap. Could it damage the motherboard or something?

Comment: The refurbished product key thankfully is on a sticker on the side of the case. There's another key sticker that's crossed out...Windows Vista apparently was installed before.

Comment: I've never heard (let alone experienced) a hard drive going faulty - particularly in this way - damaging a motherboard, so you are pretty safe there.  **The issue is one of irrecoverable/expensive to recover data loss.**